# Salesforce Code Coverage Percentage Conflict In Production

Tags: force.com

There is a conflict in the Salesforce code coverage calculation process in Production Environment. When I am going to test all the testcases in the (setup --> Apex Classes --> Run All Test Cases), it is displaying 77% overall code coverage while when i try to calculate overall percentage in Developer Console (Test Tab) then i find 88.09% . why does it so ?

Is there any code that i missed to test or some thing else or even i need to test all the triggers as well ?

Please reply fast .

Apex Test Execution Options Screenshot -

[image]

Can any one tell me the logic or process that calculates overall percentage in the salesforce production ?

My main problem is that when i am computing this percentage manually by averaging all the percentage of all classes in the developer console , I got 88.09%. why it is differing with huge percentage ? Is there any bug in the salesforce ?

Comment: Do you have any managed packages installed? And have you tried clearing all existing test results first (Setup->Develop->Apex Test Execution->View History->Clear Test Results) and then rerunning tests from the SFDC interface?

Comment: Yes , I First deleted all the existing test results then after i go for test each time. But this didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have any managed packages installed though?

Comment: What does it mean "Managed Packages" ?

Comment: Setup -> Installed Packages... Is there anything in that list?

Comment: No there is not any list in Installed Packages as well as Uninstalled Packages.

Comment: I'm having this kind of issue also and still waiting from SF support feedback :-(

Comment: so please click on the Star(Favorite Question) button to make this blog buzz .

Answer (score 3):

By using the Tooling API we can get the following information:

1) How many lines are covered for a specific class or trigger:

SELECT NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered
FROM ApexCodeCoverage
WHERE ApexClassOrTriggerId =

2) Which lines are covered for a specific class or trigger:

SELECT Coverage
FROM ApexCodeCoverage
WHERE ApexClassOrTriggerId =

3) The current org-wide coverage:

SELECT PercentCovered
FROM ApexOrgWideCoverage

If you haven't used tooling API, I can also explain you how

Comment: No , I dont know how to use tooling api .Do i need to run these above queries into the database to get the test results ? or Explain me how can i get real percentage of code coverage ?

Comment: How do i use Tooling API ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you have the Aggregate code coverage option checked in apex test execution.

Please follow the below steps to know the exact code coverage all the time ----

setup --> apex test execution ---> click on Options ---> uncheck the Store only aggregate code coverage option.

setup --> apex test execution ---->view test history and clear all test history

setup --> apex classes ---> compile all classes

setup ---> apex test execution ---> run all test

after the run is completed, check the overall code coverage.

You can now see that the overall code coverage for your ORG is 88.09%

Comment: No , the Store only aggregate code coverage option is already unchecked. Only Disable Parallel Apex Testing Option is checked. see the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to use Tooling API ---

To test these queries you may use Workbench (workbench.developerforce.com) as follows: 
1) Go to Utilities | REST Explorer 
2) Select GET 
3) Enter the following URL:

/services/data/v29.0/tooling/query/?q=YOUR_QUERY

where YOUR_QUERY should be the query to execute 
4) Click "Show Raw Response". 
5) For instance, if SELECT PercentCovered FROM ApexOrgWideCoverage is used, this is the format of the response:

{ 
"size" : 1, 
"totalSize" : 1, 
"done" : true, 
"records" : [ { 
"attributes" : { 
"type" : "ApexOrgWideCoverage" 
}, 
"PercentCovered" : 0 
} ], 
"queryLocator" : null, 
"entityTypeName" : "ApexOrgWideCoverage" 
}

Comment: I done this process and got the same percentage(77%) that i got it from the salesforce environment.